# Can't get form posts to be stored in the database

Tags: mysql, database, forms

I can't figure out why the posts from my form won't save in the database.

This is the html:

```
<button type="button" class="write">Write Reviews</button>
<form class="writeForm"method="post">
<input type="text" required name="monicker" placeholder="Name">
<textarea name="review" required maxlength="5000" placeholder="Leave your review here &#40;max 25,000 charachters&#41;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the php:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli::real_connect('localhost', 'user_name', 'not_password');
mysqli::select_db('db_name',$dbc);
$monicker = mysqli::real_escape_string ($_POST['monicker']);
$review = mysqli::real_escape_string ($_POST['review']);
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$query = "INSERT INTO reviews 
            (id, monicker, review, date) 
            VALUES (DEFAULT,'$monicker', '$review', 'CURDATE()');";
    mysqlI::query($dbc, $query);
}
mysqlI::close();
?>
```

Comment: echo query and note that CURDATE() don't need '' Also, remove id from both the columns and the values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didnt execute your query :
Add this line.

```
$result = $mysqli::query($query);
```

I modified your code, please check this code :

```
  <?php
            $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'communi3_root', 'typeset');
            mysql_select_db('communi3_cfds',$dbc);

            $monicker = isset($_POST['monicker']) ? mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['monicker']) : '';
            $review = isset($_POST['review']) ? mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['review']) : '';

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $query = "INSERT INTO reviews (id, monicker, review, date) VALUES (DEFAULT,'$monicker', '$review', '$current_date');";
                $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error($dbc));
            }
            mysql_close();
        ?>
```

I found an issues in your previous code :
1. No checking on your POST variables. It causes error because you used it directly without checking if it is set or not.
2. CURDATE() is an undefined function, use PHP date function instead.

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect the changes I made to my code, however it still doesn't work. Do I need to make the submit post or something? It's currently like this: `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: please print your post array
print_r($_POST);

Comment: I tried to get the array to print but it wouldn't do it. I'm thinking of getting someone to sit down with me and figure it out.

Comment: This feels like a BIG step backwards :-(

Comment: @Strawberry i dont understand what are you trying to imply. He just sent me an email, an solve I tried to solve the problem. I just posted it here to update the post @.@

Comment: In that case I suggest you read up on the deprecation of PHP's mysql_ API, SQL injection, and the importance of prepared statements.

Comment: Its his choice by the way :3

Answer (score 1):

As @maku said, you need to execute the query. But there is also more to it.

You have added `$mysql_query`, this is incorrect.

1. It is the wrong API (mysql vs. mysqli).
2. You also need to include your db connection.
3. If your `id` column is `auto_increment`, there is no need to insert it. Happens automatically.
4. There is no reason to assign a variable to the query because you are not selecting anything.
5. I would recommend using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead, then you don't need to use `mysqli::real_escape_string`.

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

       $query = "INSERT INTO reviews (id, monicker, review, date) 
                 VALUES (DEFAULT,'$monicker', '$review', 'CURDATE()')";

       mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc);
   }
   mysqli::close();
   ```

Comment: Still not working. Fixed 1 & 2. Left 3 as it is. Fixed 4. Not sure I need 5. Added html to the question.

Comment: I added the error code but there are no errors showing. It's just not going into the database. I suspect it could be my submit button.

Comment: @user2964055 - Is the PHP in the same file as the form? Try `isset($_POST['submit'])` as updated in my answer, you want to base it on the name, not the value so it should be lowercase. You can also add `echo "test"; exit;` inside the `isset` to verify the form submitted.

Comment: I changed both the name and value, as well as the post statement to lowercase and it didn't seem to do anything. I tried to run the test as well but couldn't make that work either. I may have to get someone to sit down with me and look at this.